# Login and executing PostgreSQL script automation using PostgreSQL role in Ansible playbook

Tags: ansible

Required some help on Ansible script

- Login and executing some samples required using Ansible playbook.

No need to install PostgreSQL.

We tried with below command but it's not working.

```
- name: Login to DB and run command 
  command:PGPASSWORD='{{pgpass_filepath}}'; psql -U "{{ db_user }}" -d "{{ db_name }}" -h "{{ db_host }}" -p 5555-c "select count(*) from student";
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to keep in mind that you have to escape the bracket characters, also the ; at the end of the sql statement needs to be inside the escaped brackets. I would also advise you to let ansible execute the shell command with a white space at the beginning so the command with the password won't be logged to the shell history.

```
- name: Login to DB and run command
  shell: " PGPASSWORD='{{pgpass_filepath}}' psql -U {{ db_user }} -d {{ db_name }} -h {{ db_host }} -p 5555 -c \"select count(*) from student;\""
```

This should work. Give it a try.

Comment: Hi Thanks for your reply.I tried with  your suggestion but I am getting the following error now "stderr": "/bin/sh: psql: command not found", "stdout

Comment: Hi Thanks for your reply.I tried with  your suggestion but I am getting the following error now "stderr": "/bin/sh: psql: command not found", "stdout

Comment: You need to have the psql client installed on the machine where you execute the playbook. On Ubuntu e.g. https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=postgresql-client

Comment: To be clearer. It has to be installed on the host you defined in the hosts file and which is used as target of the playbook.

Comment: HI Manually we tried from pgsql command its for fine for the same user. But through ansible playbook its not working.

Comment: Hi Now Psql command issue is resolved.we are getting below error now."stderr": "sh: PGPASSWORD='test' psql -U u_vip -d test1-h test2 -p 12400: No such file or directory"

Comment: HI guys i  tried in different ways and s also with your solution but i am facing this issue now.No such file or directory", "stdout": "", "stdout_lines":  command: sh "PGPASSWORD='test'; psql -U u_test -d test1 -h test2 -p 999-f sh \"/tmp/script.sql;\"" please correct me if any thing wrong i am doing.

Comment: HI i can able to connect to DB successfully with out any errors but .sql script file is not executing. name: Connect to postgres
  shell: |
      export PGPASSWORD="{{ 1234}}" && \
      .~admin/.profile >/dev/null \
      /opt/rh/rh-postgresql95/root/usr/bin/psql\
      -h "{{ db_host }}" \
      -d test1 \
      -U test2\
      -p 888\
      -f /test/script.sql 2>&1
      exit 0
      always_run: yes